# How to add a code for lastpostdate after/inside a specific menu link?

Tags: php, menus

So, I have a news website. The designers want me to have a link in the menu that says "Latest News - [time of the last post]".

I know I can get the datetime of the latest post with get_lastpostdate().

But how can I put this php code inside the menu? This specific link is not the first one nor the last. It's inside the menu structure. Menus in this website are made trough the usual custom menu tools of wp.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using Navigation Walker class you can customize menu items in WP menu. Check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)

Comment: What should I look for? Ok, extend the walker class. But how can I access from inside the walker one specific menu item and add code to it? Wouldn't a filter be better? Because I really have to do this just once.

Comment: Yes, you can also use filter. Filter `wp_get_nav_menu_items` is available. `args` parameter is passed in both Walker class and filter also. Both method is applicable and you can choose any one. In filter three parameters are passed. `return apply_filters( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items',  $items, $menu, $args );`

Comment: Should I use $item to pass the name of the menu link?